# State Server Session State in .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to add `sessionState mode="StateServer"` to ASP.NET Core 2, but cannot find examples.

Trying to follow steps from [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43187/How-Do-I-Setup-an-ASP-NET-Application-to-Use-State), but I'm unable to edit the auto-generated `web.config` to add sessionState node and not clear how to configure services in `startup.cs`.

Samples I found are for a [distributed cache for SQLServer and REDIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed).

1. Is it possible to use `StateServer` mode for Session State in .NET Core 2?
2. If Yes, would you, please, point to some example of how to configure `appsettings.json` to add variables similar to `sessionState mode="StateServer"`?

Comment: if you use the session, test that you request can still run in parallel, as in ASP.NET - writing to the session locks it, so that request would be squential. see: Concurrent Requests and Session State here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx ..  I think writing your own redis code is better.  rather than binding to session.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#working-with-session-state for instructions on setting up Session State.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to edit the web.config? Where in your project folder is the web.config file?

Answer (score 3):

No, session depends on IDistributedCache for storage. In other word, The session data is backed by a cache.
We have providers for Redis and SQL, or you can provide your own implementation.
There is nothing like configuring SessionState mode in .net core as it was in earlier Asp.net.

Implementation of IDistributedCache will determine the configurations for session.