# Is there a "stateServer" equivalent for Blazor?

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

Back in the day, in old Asp.Net land, we used to use stateServer to prevent session information being lost during a server restart (or Redis of course).

I'm now working on a Blazor Server project (or production slot swapping more these days) and during a swap, all clients then restart (due to the SignalR connection resetting obviously), which is obviously not ideal. I understand why this is the case, but it does create a bad experience for users of the site.

Is there a "stateServer" type equivalent to prevent this type of client restart in Blazor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State Server Session State in .NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516258/state-server-session-state-in-net-core-2)

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248782/session-state-in-asp-net-core) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#signalrblazor-server-and-http-context-based-state-management)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn No because that's state server in .net core (the thing I was comparing it with), I'm not sure if you've understood my question, it's looking for if there is an equivalent in Blazor

Comment: Blazor is in .NET Core and i linked even resources regarding explicitly Blazor.

Comment: I see, I read them as specifically session state, rather than the Blazor connection, unless I've misunderstood that